# When doing free radical substitution, is the free radical a catalyst?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, catalysis

Consider a simple free radical substitution's propagation step for $\ce{CH4}$ to $\ce{CH3Cl}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{CH4 + Cl^. &-> CH3^. + HCl}\tag{R1}\\
\ce{CH3^. + Cl2 &-> CH3Cl + Cl^.}\tag{R2}
\end{align}
$$

My understanding is that since the free radical is regenerated at the end of the reaction, it must therefore be a catalyst of some sort. Is this understanding correct or flawed?

Comment: You may find useful these links for text formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: Yes, $\ce{Cl^•}$ acts as a catalyst here.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks for letting me know! I was trying to find the command for the last 5 mins but couldn't find it and thus went for the last resort!

Comment: Hmm,  $\ce{Cl^.}$ as `$\ce{Cl^.}$` - nice!

Comment: @Poutnik No need for `\bullet`, `\cdot` or other macro or Unicode chars. Just use `^.`, as it's stated in manuals for [MathJax-mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/), [$\mathrm\LaTeX$-mhchem](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem), or another package [chemformula](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemformula).

Comment: See also [IUPAC Gold book: Catalyst](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C00876)

Comment: @Poutnik thank you for the help with formatting in chemicals. I find it very useful.

Comment: @Poutnik Following the gold book, I know realize that this is a case of autocatalysis. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is interesting. As you state, the free radical $\ce{Cl·}$ is regenerated at the end of the reaction. It behaves like  Vanadium(V) which oxidizes $\ce{SO2}$ into $\ce{SO3}$. And once reduced into Vanadium(IV), it gets reoxidized by $\ce{O2}$ into Vanadium(V), according to the two equations $$\ce{V2O5 + 2 SO2 -> 2 VO2 + 2 SO3}$$
$$\ce{2 VO2 + O2 -> V2O5}$$ The main difference between the free radical substitution and the vanadium oxide catalysis is the fact that both vanadium oxides do exist as stable compounds. And the radical $\ce{Cl·}$ is not stable and cannot be isolated.

Comment: The question is, if we should consider transient, intermediate products in nonlinear complex reactions as catalysts. IUPAC Gold book seems to do so, but.....

Answer (score 0):

Well, consider this argument on the undoubtedly actual expanded system, which would commence with the action of strong UV on a Chlorine gas in presence of Methane, and seemingly would proceed based on random kinetics, as follows:

\begin{align}
\ce{Cl2 + UV &-> Cl^.  + Cl^.}\\
\ce{CH4 + Cl^. &-> CH3^. + HCl}\\
\ce{CH3^. + Cl2 &-> CH3Cl + Cl^.}\\
\ce{Cl^.  + Cl^. &-> Cl2}\\
\ce{CH3^. + CH3^. &-> Products}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

where not all reactions are equally likely again based on kinetics.

In the above more complex system approaching reality, I would claim the Chlorine presence (certainly in the form of the $\ce{Cl^.}$) has catalytic aspects. Note, both the chlorine radical and the methane radical are cycled within the system, albeit, the methane radical self-reaction is a termination step, whereas the chlorine radical self-reaction restarts the system. However, Chlorine is consumed in the system so not by definition a catalyst.

Comment: Good point that chlorine is consumed. Only the radicals regenerate each other. I don't see what you mean by "kinetics", likely the wrong word.

Comment: On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: @Karl won't the radicals be consumed if a chlorine radical hits a methyl radical?

Comment: MaguireFan123: Yes, indeed .CH3 + .Cl = CH3Cl  and the reverse may also be possible under UV light. Note: my use of dots to convene possible continuation of reactions.